# How to limit each user to only allowed to post once every 24 hours in Django Class Based Create View

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-class-based-views

In views.py:

```
class AddPostView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    login_url = '/member/login'
    model=Post
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name='post/addpost.html'
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.poster = self.request.user
        return super(AddPostView, self).form_valid(form)
```

In forms.py

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
      model = Post
      fields = ('title','somefields...')
      labels = {'somelabels': '...'}
      widgets = {'some css attributes....'}
      def has_posted_today(self):
          yesterday = timezone.now() - timezone.timedelta(hours=24)
          poster = self.cleaned_data.get('poster')
          if Post.objects.filter(poster=poster, post_date__gt=yesterday).exists():
              raise forms.ValidationError("You have already posted today, Come back tomorrow!")
```

in models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    poster = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True)
    ...somefields = ...somemodels
```

If this were a function based view i would imagine the solutions would be something like...

```
if request.method == "POST":
    yesterday = timezone.now() - timezone.timedelta(days=1)
    if Post.objects.filter(poster=request.user, post_date__gt=yesterday).exists():
        return HttpResponseForbidden("You have already posted today, Come back tomorrow!")
```

First quesiton, my code does not work....how do i make it work....

Second question, How do u do the HttpResponseForbidden thing in a django class based view.

Comment: This might help solving the 24 hour problem: Have a look at user_passes_test functionality https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users-that-pass-a-test.

Comment: i added the following to addpostview in views.py, did not work, `def test_func(self):
            yesterday = timezone.now() - timezone.timedelta(days=1)
            return Post.objects.filter(poster=self.request.user, 
            post_date__gt=yesterday).exists()`

Comment: Acutally it worked when i add return False, But when i tried to redirect, it gave me this error of AddPostView didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Comment: @alv2017 I think i got it, Thank you!

Comment: glad that it helped to find the solution ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In views.py:

```
class AddPostView(UserPassesTestMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    login_url = '/member/login'
    model=Post
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name='post/addpost.html'
    def test_func(self):
        yesterday = datetime.now() - timedelta(day=1)
        #print to see which time is correct.
        print('this is yesterday...', yesterday)
        print('this is timezone.now()...', timezone.now())
        print('this is daytime.now()...', datetime.now())
        if Post.objects.filter(poster=self.request.user, post_date__gt=yesterday).exists():
            raise PermissionDenied("You have made your post today, Please come back later")
            return False
        else:
            return True
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.poster = self.request.user
        return super(AddPostView, self).form_valid(form)
```

In 403.html:

```
{%extends 'base.html'%}
{%block content%}
    {%if exception%}
        <h1>{{exception}}</h1>
    {%else%}
        <h1>Somethings Wrong!</h1>
    {%endif%}
{%endblock%}
```